# Loop writing help needed! Need to find peak data values. python-2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, scipy

Can anybody help me write a loop that takes a list of data and checks if a value in the data is greater than the previous value and greater than the next value too. i.e. I am trying to find the peak data points in a set of peaks.

Comment: showing your attempts would be nice..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: no attempts made so far as I don't understand how to write loops very well

Answer (score 0):

You may write a loop like this:

```
lst = [1,5,3,2,4,1]

for i in range(1, len(lst)-1):
    if lst[i - 1] < lst[i] and lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
        print(i, lst[i])
```

Python tutorial:

- [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)
- [range() function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a go!